# Avoiding of printing full package name of method in log4j

Tags: log4j

I have an API that uses log4j for logging. When I have used the API in my project, though log statements related to project printed with ontl method name, but log statements coming from API is printed full package name format.
In log4j.properties file  I am using  "%c" (lowercase).

How I can force all project log statements get printed only method name.

Lets say;

I have two classes Main.java and AlarmCategoryImpl.java
AlarmCategroryImpl.java is located on API class, Main.java is defined in my project class.

```
 static Logger                       logger = Logger.getLogger(AlarmCategoryImpl.class);
 static Logger               logger   = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
```

and its log4j output.

```
 2012-12-01/18:13:22.220/EET [INFO][Main->main] starting...  
2012-12-01/18:13:22.447/EET [INFO][com.monitor.base.alarmmanagement.alarmconfigurationImpl.AlarmCategoryImpl->copyStructureRecursive] Copying AlarmCategoryImpl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` means "category name", which is synonymous to "logger name". That means that `%c` will be expanded to the logger's name.

The logger name is *not* necessarily the fully-qualified class name. The logger name is the string that is passed in to `Logger.getLogger()`. Therefore, if you have a class named `x.y.z.MyClass`, and it has this:

`private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("hello");`

Then log statements will be generated with `hello` expanded instead of `%c`.

That means that the classes in your API are using `getLogger()`, passing the class name as a parameter. That causes `%c` to be expanded to the fully-qualified class name when the logs print.

I'm guessing that your non-API classes (in other words, your own project's classes) don't pass-in any value to `Logger.getLogger()`, or perhaps they use the root logger. To be sure, paste here the line of your code that retrieves the `Logger` instance.

**EDIT** as per comment:

Well, is it possible that your `Main` class is inside the default package? (that is, it is not associated with any package)? If yes, then I don't see any problem.

`[INFO][Main->main]`: `INFO` is the level, `Main` is the class, `main` is the method.

`[INFO][com.monitor.base.alarmmanagement.alarmconfigurationImpl.AlarmCategoryImpl->copyStructureRecursive]`: `INFO` is the level, `com.monitor.base.alarmmanagement.alarmconfigurationImpl.AlarmCategoryImpl` is the class, `copyStructureRecursive` is the method.

Comment: Your `Main` class is probably in the default package, therefore it really isn't associated with any package. That's why the package component in the printout is empty; it simply doesn't exist. I updated my answer.

Comment: You are right, the reason why Main class log is printed only its name is because Main is not associated wit any package. So as you recommended, I have updated the definition with logger.getLogger("AlarmcategoryImpl");. Problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you could leave things as they are and replace `%c` with `%C{1}`. This will only show the rightmost component of the fully qualified name, which means - will only display the class' name. Note that this approach, though, might impose some performance issues if you're doing extensive logging. You can read about it here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: ... Or leave it as `%c`, and instead of sending `XYZ.class.getName()`, send `ClassUtils.getShortClassName(XYZ.class)`. `ClassUtils` is included with Commons Lang, which is a very popular third-party set of utilities.